# A way to do org-toggle-link-display at point

Tags: org-mode

Is there a function that toggle's the display of the link at point only?

I tried to check the source of `org-toggle-link-display` to see if it can be adjusted to be done on one link only, but from my understanding it's a characteristic for all the links that can't be done on individual links.

```
;; Taken from ol.el
(defun org-toggle-link-display ()
  "Toggle the literal or descriptive display of links."
  (interactive)
  (if org-link-descriptive (remove-from-invisibility-spec '(org-link))
    (add-to-invisibility-spec '(org-link)))
  (org-restart-font-lock)
  (setq org-link-descriptive (not org-link-descriptive)))
```

Comment: I don't know of any such function. Whether it's easy/possilbe to write such a function is an open question.

Comment: You could automate narrowing the buffer to just the link at point and toggling link display, but that would mean showing *only* the expanded link, with none of its surrounding context. You could also automate doing that in a temporary "clone" buffer opened in another window or frame while the original remains visible, which might be closer to what you want.